# MS outlook 2016 VBA - Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder - doesn't seem to be working (it did in OL2007)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, rules, microsoft-outlook-2016

I copied some specific VBA code a few years ago into outlook 2007.  It runs my rules on the current folder I have selected.  The company just upgraded to outlook 2016 (office 365) and although the VBA code was retained (in "ThisOutlookSession") it no longer works.

Is there perhaps some VBA code present that's no longer supported?

```
Sub RunAllInboxRules()
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim runrule As String
Dim rulename As String

rulename = "DBLP RULE"

Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore

Set myRules = st.GetRules
Set cf = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
For Each rl In myRules

If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then

If rl.Name = rulename Then
rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=cf
runrule = rl.Name

End If
End If
Next

Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub
```

I also tried

```
Set st = Application.Session.Stores(1)
```

because I saw that someone else had an issue with DefaultStore.  That didn't resolve it.

I also tried explicitly stating the rulename:

```
If rl.Name = "DBLP RULE" Then
```

Again, that didn't cause it to work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The rule is not running against the currently selected folder, so something in this VBA code is clearly not compatible with outlook 2016.  When the rule is run manually it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the code is fine.  Although I did change the macro security setting to allow the macros to run (after installing outlook 2016) it didn't take effect upon restarting outlook.  I restarted it a few more times and it took effect.

It's interesting to note that I didn't get a popup stating that the macro is disabled.

Issue now resolved.